# Changing Task Name font color when Percent Complete equals 100 - MS Project

Tags: vba, macros, ms-project

Program: MS Project 2013 Professional

I am trying to change the Task Name font color to green when the % Complete is equal to 100%. This is what I have, but it is still not working for me.

```
Sub TurnGreen100Complete()
' 100% Task Completion - Turn Green

    Dim T As Task

    For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
        Select Case T.PercentComplete
            Case Is = "100%"
                SelectTaskField Row:=T.Name, RowRelative:=False
                Font Color:=pjGreen
        End Select
    Next T
End Sub
```

Comment: `PercentComplete` returns a number not a string.  so try `Case 100`

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Dim T As Task

```
For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If not t is nothing then  'Ignore blank rows
      If T.PercentComplete=100 then
          editgoto ID:=t.id
          Font Color:=pjGreen
      End If
    End IF
Next T
```